# How to set chart width and height with phpSpreadsheet

Tags: charts, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to set the size of an Excel chart created by phpSpreadsheet.

I used the following code, but the layout settings do not seem to have any effect:

```
// Define chart position and size
$layout = new Layout();
$layout->setXPosition(10);
$layout->setYPosition(50);
$layout->setWidth(400);
$layout->setHeight(300);

//  Set the series in the plot area
$plotArea = new PlotArea($layout, [$series]);
//  Set the chart legend
$legend = new Legend(Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, null, false);

$title = new Title('Test');
$yAxisLabel = new Title('y');

//  Create the chart
$chart = new Chart(
    'chart1', // name
    $title, // title
    $legend, // legend
    $plotArea, // plotArea
    true, // plotVisibleOnly
    0, // displayBlanksAs
    null, // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel  // yAxisLabel
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit chart width and height setting. Instead, define left-top and right-bottom cells for chart area like so:

```
$chart->setTopLeftPosition('A1');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('M9');
$worksheet->addChart($chart);
```

See chart example e.g. [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/316).